# a-frame on mouse click cursor disappearing issue with aframe-extra version 3.8.6

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

I am using https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.8.6/dist/aframe-extras.min.js aframe extra version **3.8.6** with aframe version **0.6.0** , on mouse clicked cursor is disappearing, need to pressed esc key everytime to get cursor back.
can someone please help me into this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's intentional, so you won't have to move around constantly clicking around.

You can disable it quite easily by switching

```
look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"
```

to

```
look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false"
```

I see your version also has the `pointerLockEnabled` property.

---

Nonetheless, i would recommend switching to the newest [a-frame build](https://aframe.io/docs/master/introduction/) + [a-frame extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras), since there was a ton of polishing and bug-fixes.

---

[Glitch](https://stack-50444846.glitch.me/) with `pointerLockEnabled: true` 
[Glitch](https://stack-50444846.glitch.me/disabled.html) with `pointerLockEnabled: false` 
source [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-50444846?path=index.html:32:58).